# Changing the From clause based on ComboBox Value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I was working on a dialog box in Access that essentially had this function. I wanted a user to select a table from a combo box and it'd then change the query to create a select view of the necessary information. Here is the code of the dialog box

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim strSQL As String
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryPendingQS")

strSQL = "SELECT [Event Start Date] AS [Event Date], [PO Sent _Date] AS [PO Sent Date], [Brand Name] AS Vendor, PO, [Units _Sold] AS [Units Sold], [Routing Date/Time EST] AS Shipped, [Date and _Time of Arrival] AS ETA, [Department Name] AS Category " & _
         "FROM Me.cbotable.Value " & _
         "WHERE table3 ='" & Me.cbotable.Value & "';"

    qdf.SQL = strSQL

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPendingQS"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing   
    End Sub
```

Things are fine for the most part but the problem arises in this part of the statement.

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Event Start Date] AS [Event Date], [PO Sent _Date] AS [PO Sent Date], [Brand Name] AS Vendor, PO, [Units _Sold] AS [Units Sold], [Routing Date/Time EST] AS Shipped, [Date and _Time of Arrival] AS ETA, [Department Name] AS Category " & _
         "FROM table3" & _
         "WHERE table3 ='" & Me.cbotable.Value & "';"
```

This is from a previous attempt but I am aware that you can't change tables based off a WHERE clause. So my question is, how can I change the FROM statement dynamically based off of what is selected in the combobox

This is how the SQL code looks when the query attempts to execute:

```
SELECT [Event Start Date] AS [Event Date], [PO Sent _Date] AS [PO Sent Date], [Brand Name] AS Vendor, PO, [Units _Sold] AS [Units Sold], [Routing Date/Time EST] AS Shipped, [Date and _Time of Arrival] AS ETA, [Department Name] AS Category 
FROM table3  
WHERE table3 ='QS Log';
```

Comment: What is going on with your code?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @HansUp The error comes when it is trying to execute the code at 'DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPendingQS"' Because you can't change a FROM value via a WHERE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to the conflict myself, as I learned you can not pass parameters through SQL code. Being that I had my code within VBA I decided to split the SQL statements into two strings, one containing "Select * From " and the other string becoming the combobox value. I then add the values together to make one string and pushed it to the query.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

   Dim Db As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim strSQL As String
   Set Db = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = Db.QueryDefs("qryPendingQS")

   Dim strQryFirstPart As String
   Dim strQryWhole As String
   Dim strTableName As String

   strQryFirstPart = "Select * FROM "
   strTableName = Me.cbotable.Value
   strQryWhole = strQryFirstPart & "[" & strTableName & "]"

   qdf.SQL = strQryWhole

    Debug.Print strQryWhole



End Sub
```

A bit of a workaround but it got the solution.